# need for deriving iostream from istream and ostream

Tags: c++, io

while studying `I/O` I came across:

> iostream: istream reads from a stream, ostream writes to a stream, iostream reads and writes a stream: derived from istream and ostream

What is the need of inheritance if `istream` and `ostream` do the same job?

Comment: They don't do the same job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly by making `iostream` inherit from `istream` and from `ostream` you get a class that supports input and output and both interfaces (from `istream` and `ostream`). That doesn't mean that functionality is duplicated, it just means that the interfaces of `istream` and `ostream` and their implementation is being reused.

Answer (score 1):

The prototypes for a writer and reader are

```
class MyClass;
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream stream&, const MyClass &obj)
{
    obj->WriteTo(stream);
    return stream;
}

std::istream& operator>> (std::istream stream&, MyClass &obj)
{
    obj->ReadFrom(stream);
    return stream;
}
```

These functions (especially the writer) call lower-level stream functions on `MyClass`'es members.

Having `std::iostream` derived from both `std::istream` and `std::ostream` means that you can pass an instance of `std::iostream` to either function and it automatically pass in the correct part of `std::iostream` in.

`std::istream` and `std::ostream` are statically derived from `std::ios` which contains the common code for them.